# delete image with id from DB wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, database, wordpress

I want to delete image with it's ID from PHPMyAdmin DB. Table with images is `wp_posts` and ID is called `post_parent`.
Action that connects to ajax and should delete image:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_image_admin', 'delete_image_admin' );
function delete_image_admin(){

    $deleteId = $_POST['deletedId'];

    
    
    $return = array(
    'message'   => 'Сохранено',
    'ID'        => $_POST['deletedId'],
);
wp_send_json( $return );
};
```

Ajax (it's working correctly):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.image-remove-btn', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var img = $(this).closest('.thumbs');
    var id = img.find("img").data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {deletedId : id,
        action: "delete_image_admin"},
        success: function( data ) {
            img.remove();
        }    
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have time to answer, but it is important to know that PHPMyAdmin is **not** a database. It is a GUI tool to access your database, which is almost certainly MySQL or MariaDB. It might sound nit-picky, but it is a good thing to know when asking questions so that the right people can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should delete the image from wp_posts table:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_image_admin', 'delete_image_admin');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_image_admin', 'delete_image_admin');
function delete_image_admin(){
    if (!empty($_POST['deletedId'])) {
        global $wpdb;

        $deleteId = $_POST['deletedId'];

        $table = $wpdb->base_prefix . "posts";
        $wpdb->delete($table, [
            'ID' => $deleteId,
        ]);

        echo 'Image deleted';

        wp_die();
    }
};
```

Comment: I got error: `POST load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.6.4:2  https://badzingerauto.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_fs_blog_admin=true 500`

Comment: Status Code: 500

Comment: Edited. I left out the global $wpdb part.

Comment: I change your code a little bit because programmers should check if their code works correctly and it's not too good to echo `Success`. It's better to make a JSON that contains `success`

Comment: True, just wanted to give you an idea. Glad it worked :)